# Word/phrase like Schadenfreude, but a feeling of comfort or satisfaction?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or excellent, catchy description for a situation in which a person (A) feels a sense of satisfaction at another (B) having to obey the same rules as them, and the suffering that this causes, as well as feeling a corresponding discomfort or jealousy over the possibility of B not obeying/suffering in the same way as A.

Comment: Also, "misery loves company".  That is, we're "happier" (or at least bear it better) being miserable if someone else is just as miserable.

Comment: "He who mocks the poor taunts his Maker; He who rejoices at calamity will not go unpunished" (Proverbs 17:5). Also, "Do not rejoice when your enemy falls, And do not let your heart be glad when he stubles; Or the LORD will see it and be displeased, And turn His anger away from him" (Proverbs 24:19).

Answer (score 1):

Well, schadenfreude technically does fit the meaning you require, but since you need another word, how about, ***epicaricacy***?

> **epicaricacy**
>
> enjoyment obtained from the troubles of others

However the term is much more obscure than schadenfreude, and isn't in any major dictionaries.

For the other meaning you request, I think **bitterness** might work.

> **bitterness**
>
> anger and disappointment at being treated unfairly; resentment.

So, a combination of the two would come really close to the meaning you want.

> ***bitter schadenfreude***, or ***bitter epicaricacy***